# mysql join 2 table results

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables:

Sites: ID, name
Assoc: site_id, assoc_type, assoc_id
Options: ID, name

I would like to do the following query in one

```
SELECT * FROM sites
    FOREACH site SELECT * FROM assoc WHERE assoc_type='option' AND site_id = site.ID
    FOREACH assoc SELECT name FROM options WHERE ID = assoc.ID

FOREACH SITE
    echo name, array(option 1, option2, option3);
```

is this possible?

Code I am trying to shorten

```
      $getsites = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sites")or die(mysql_error());
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getsites)){
        echo $row['name'];
        $getassoc = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM assoc WHERE type='options' AND site_id = '$row[ID]'")or die(mysql_error());
        echo'<ul>';
        while($subrow = mysql_fetch_array($getassoc)){
          $getoption = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM options WHERE ID = '$subrow[assoc_id]'")or die(mysql_error());
          $option = mysql_fetch_assoc($getoption);
          echo '<li>'.$option['name'].'</li>';
       }
       echo'</ul><br/>';

       }
```

Comment: Every site is related to maximum 3 options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT s.name
     , ( SELECT o.name
         FROM Options AS o
           JOIN Assoc AS a
             ON a.assoc_id = o.ID
         WHERE a.site_id = s.id
           AND a.assoc_type='option'
         ORDER BY o.id
         LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0
       ) AS option1
     , ( SELECT o.name
         FROM Options AS o
           JOIN Assoc AS a
             ON a.assoc_id = o.ID
         WHERE a.site_id = s.id
           AND a.assoc_type='option'
         ORDER BY o.id
         LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
       ) AS option2
     , ( SELECT o.name
         FROM Options AS o
           JOIN Assoc AS a
             ON a.assoc_id = o.ID
         WHERE a.site_id = s.id
           AND a.assoc_type='option'
         ORDER BY o.id
         LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2
       ) AS option3
FROM Sites AS s
```

If you want to perform a usual join of the 3 tables, to find all sites and related options, you can use:

```
SELECT s.name AS site
     , o.name AS option
FROM Sites AS s
    JOIN Assoc AS a
        ON a.site_id = s.id
    JOIN Options AS o
        ON o.ID = a.assoc_id
WHERE a.assoc_type = 'option'
ORDER BY s.name
       , o.name
```

Comment: I have included the code I would have used if I couldnt do it with one query in the original post.

Comment: I have simplified the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627578/mysql-join-2-table-results

Comment: Thanks, the second query would return an array with the site details and a sub array for the options am i right?